# How can I get the value from JSON in logic apps

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

This is my source ( JSON)

```
{
    "Price": {
        "For": "840.040",
        "From": "2.990"
    },
    "ArticleNumber": "71151004",
    "ArticleNumberPartitionKey": "7115",
    "ForStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "id": "71151004",
  
}
```

My requirement is to get True in Logic apps( Condition) if the JSON file contains "ForStatus":"ACTIVE".
I tried with this command but not working.

```
json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['Content']))?['ForStatus']?['ACTIVE']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I don't know where your source(json) come from. I'm not sure if the expression `json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['Content']))` you provided can get the json data rather than get null value.

I assume the expression `json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['Content']))` can get the json data. To implement your requirement, you can use `json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['Content']))?['ForStatus']` **is equal to** `ACTIVE`, like below screenshot:

[image]

If the property `ForStatus` may not exist in your json data, you can use `string(json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['Content'])))` **contains** `"ForStatus":"ACTIVE"`, like below screenshot:

[image]

Please note, use `"ForStatus":"ACTIVE"`(remove blank space before `"ACTIVE"`) after the "contains" because when you use `json()` method, it will remove the blank space.

Comment: Thanks a lot... It worked, the second syntax.